# Counting rows between dates in pandas with groupby

Tags: pandas

I don't know why I can't figure this out. I am trying to find the number of rows in between certain time frames based on a customer ID column. The periods I am interested in would be 14 days from the Call_Time, 7 days, and 3 days.

df =

```
Call_Time   Customer_ID  Survey
    8/26/2015   aaa123    1
    8/27/2015   bbb222    1
```

dataframe fcr =

```
Call_Time   Customer_ID
8/14/2015   aaa123
8/7/2015    aaa123
7/15/2015   aaa123
8/22/2015   aaa123
8/3/2015    bbb222
8/8/2015    bbb222
8/10/2015   bbb222
```

Here is the code I am using now

```
fcr['Total_Hits'] = 1
g14 = fcr.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='14D',key='Call_Time'),'Customer_ID']).sum()
g7 = fcr.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='7D',key='Call_Time'),'Customer_ID']).sum()
g3 = fcr.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='3D',key='Call_Time'),'Customer_ID']).sum()
```

I then want to connect those values to another dataframe from a separate file.

```
temp = pd.merge(g14, g7, how ='left', on = ['Call_Time', 'Customer_ID'])
previous_hits = pd.merge(temp, g3, how ='left', on = ['Call_Time', 'Customer_ID'])
df2 = pd.merge(df, previous_hits, how ='left', on = ['Call_Time', 'Customer_ID'])
```

So my df2 would combine the record of all calls (fcr) to the original df which is a survey. What I want to know, for each customer who filled out a survey, how many times did they call before filling out that survey within 14, 7, or 3 days? Are scores lower for customers who called in many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html).
[Doc example](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#grouping-with-a-grouper-specification)

Firstly I have to use function `pd.to_datetime`, because my column `Call_Time` isn't `datetime64 dtype`. Then I add `Count` column with scalar value `1` and sum it by recommended frequency and column `Customer_ID`.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""Call_Time,Customer_ID
8/14/2015 0:00,aaa123
8/7/2015 0:00,aaa123
7/15/2015 0:00,aaa123
8/22/2015 0:00,aaa123
8/3/2015 0:00,bbb222
8/8/2015 0:00,bbb222
8/10/2015 0:00,bbb222"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=True)
#time format - http://strftime.org/
df['Call_Time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Call_Time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
#set column quantity - each time user call once 
df["Count"] = 1
print df
#
#   Call_Time Customer_ID     Count
#0 2015-08-14      aaa123         1
#1 2015-08-07      aaa123         1
#2 2015-07-15      aaa123         1
#3 2015-08-22      aaa123         1
#4 2015-08-03      bbb222         1
#5 2015-08-08      bbb222         1
#6 2015-08-10      bbb222         1
#
#grouping by frequency and Customer_ID
g14 = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='14D',key='Call_Time'),'Customer_ID']).sum()
g7 = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='7D',key='Call_Time'),'Customer_ID']).sum()
g3 = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='3D',key='Call_Time'),'Customer_ID']).sum()

print g14
print g7
print g3

#
#                           Count
#Call_Time  Customer_ID
#2015-07-15 aaa123              1
#2015-07-29 aaa123              1
#           bbb222              3
#2015-08-12 aaa123              2
#                           Count
#Call_Time  Customer_ID
#2015-07-15 aaa123              1
#2015-07-29 bbb222              1
#2015-08-05 aaa123              1
#           bbb222              2
#2015-08-12 aaa123              1
#2015-08-19 aaa123              1
#                           Count
#Call_Time  Customer_ID
#2015-07-15 aaa123              1
#2015-08-02 bbb222              1
#2015-08-05 aaa123              1
#2015-08-08 bbb222              2
#2015-08-14 aaa123              1
#2015-08-20 aaa123              1
```

Grouper sorting date column itself and you can use sorting `Call_Time` by `Customer_ID` only for checking data:

```
df =  df.groupby("Customer_ID", sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort('Call_Time')).drop('Customer_ID', axis=1)
df = df.reset_index(0)
```

**EDIT:** 
I don't know I understand correctly, so I modified my solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp1=u"""Call_Time,Customer_ID,Survey
8/26/2015,aaa123,1
8/27/2015,bbb222,1"""

temp=u"""Call_Time,Customer_ID
8/14/2015 0:00,aaa123
8/7/2015 0:00,aaa123
7/15/2015 0:00,aaa123
8/22/2015 0:00,aaa123
8/3/2015 0:00,bbb222
8/8/2015 0:00,bbb222
8/10/2015 0:00,bbb222"""

fcr = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=True)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp1), parse_dates=True)
fcr['Call_Time'] =  pd.to_datetime(fcr['Call_Time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
df['Call_Time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Call_Time'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

fcr['Total_Hits'] = 1
g14 = fcr.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='14D',key='Call_Time'),'Customer_ID']).sum().reset_index()
g7 = fcr.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='7D',key='Call_Time'),'Customer_ID']).sum().reset_index()
g3 = fcr.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='3D',key='Call_Time'),'Customer_ID']).sum().reset_index()

g14 = g14.rename(columns={'Total_Hits':'Total_Hits_14'})
g7 = g7.rename(columns={'Total_Hits':'Total_Hits_7'})
g3 = g3.rename(columns={'Total_Hits':'Total_Hits_3'})

temp = pd.merge(g14, g7, how ='outer', on = ['Call_Time', 'Customer_ID'])
previous_hits = pd.merge(temp, g3, how ='outer', on = ['Call_Time', 'Customer_ID'])

df2 = pd.merge(df, previous_hits, how ='left', on = ['Customer_ID'])
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'Call_Time_x':'Call_Time', 'Call_Time_y':'Call_Time_fcr'})

print df2
#
#    Call_Time Customer_ID  Survey Call_Time_fcr  Total_Hits_14  Total_Hits_7  \
#0  2015-08-26      aaa123       1    2015-07-15              1             1
#1  2015-08-26      aaa123       1    2015-07-29              1           NaN
#2  2015-08-26      aaa123       1    2015-08-12              2             1
#3  2015-08-26      aaa123       1    2015-08-05            NaN             1
#4  2015-08-26      aaa123       1    2015-08-19            NaN             1
#5  2015-08-26      aaa123       1    2015-08-14            NaN           NaN
#6  2015-08-26      aaa123       1    2015-08-20            NaN           NaN
#7  2015-08-27      bbb222       1    2015-07-29              3             1
#8  2015-08-27      bbb222       1    2015-08-05            NaN             2
#9  2015-08-27      bbb222       1    2015-08-02            NaN           NaN
#10 2015-08-27      bbb222       1    2015-08-08            NaN           NaN

#    Total_Hits_3
#0              1
#1            NaN
#2            NaN
#3              1
#4            NaN
#5              1
#6              1
#7            NaN
#8            NaN
#9              1
#10             2
```

I reset multiindex in `g14`, `g7` and `g3` appending `reset_index()`.
I think better in dataframe `previous_hits` is using union of keys from both frames (`how ='outer'`).
For elegance I rename multiple columns. It isn't necessary.

Comment: Ill know in about an hour when I go to the office. FYI

Comment: To join the data back to the original dataframe as a new column I will need to add call time and a column called employee_id. I'm connecting these rows back to another dataframe which has the customer id

Comment: I dont understand exactly. My output columns Call_Time are 14,7 and 3 days 'windows' (depends of minimal time of source - in my example 2015-07-15) and only this minimal time is in output and others arent present there. I think the best idea is example of your output and I try to extend my solution for your requirements.

Comment: Edited my original comment - I would like to be able to merge the results of my grouped total counts to another dataframe which has 1 record for each customer ID. The total counts should be the number of times the customer ID showed up in the raw data before the timestamp on the original df